# Why is my array not empty when it has just been declared

Tags: javascript

I set up an empty array, then I'm doing a "for loop" where I set up an empty object, add things to the empty object and finally push the object onto an array.

Technically the array in the beginning should be empty but when I console log it, it still has objects in it. How is that?

[image]

```js
function displayIngredients(cocktail) {
  // console.log(cocktail);
  let ingredients = [];
  console.log(ingredients);


  let i;
  for (i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    const ingredientsMeasure = {};
    if (cocktail[`strIngredient${i}`] !== '') {
      ingredientsMeasure.ingredient = cocktail[`strIngredient${i}`];
      ingredientsMeasure.measurement = cocktail[`strMeasure${i}`];
      ingredients.push(ingredientsMeasure);
    }
  }
  console.log(ingredients);

}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it to make a [mcve] - add the cocktail object

Comment: It's probably just a matter of visualization in the console. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(ingredients));` to inspect the actual contents at the time of logging.

Comment: Do you see that blue "i"? Hover over it, it will give you the answer.

Comment: Chrome needs a little Clippit character to say _"Looks like you're using `console.log()` to do debugging. That's bad, you should use the debugger instead. Here's how..."_

Answer (score 1):

console.log() is passed a reference to the object, so the value in the Console changes as the object changes. To avoid that you can:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ingredients)))
```

Comment: Please, do not answer duplicates.